# How to make Django Form repeatedly submit in background while user is filling it in?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

#### Background information about my project:

I'm building a CV/Resume generator that automatically creates a CV/Resume based on the user filling out a form. I'm using a Django Crispy Form which has a submit button at the end that, when clicked, submits the user's input to a SQL database and redirects the user to their newly built CV/Resume (as a PDF).

#### What I need help with:

The goal is to have a form on the left side of the screen and a live view (HTML/CSS) of the CV/Resume on the right side, where the live view updates as the user is filling out the form.

I've seen this kind of thing before, but never for a Django project (they tend to use JavaScript/React).

#### What I'm thinking:

Could I have a background process that does something like, when the user makes a change (e.g. is filling out the form), submit any new inputs to the SQL database every 5 seconds? Then the live view can extract any new inputs from the database and display it in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to do something like that with ajax requests, but I wouldn't recommend it. It would be better to render a simulation of it in the browser with javascript html and css. That way you avoid many many needless post requests before the user is ready to submit the form.

Comment: Would you be able to explain what you mean by "render a simulation of it in the browser with JavaScript, HTML and CSS"? FYI, I don't know any JavaScript, so in that sense I'm very much a beginner.

Comment: Javascript is the programming language inside all modern web browsers. With it you can write code to run inside the users browser. Almost all of the interactive, dynamic or animated elements you see on a webpage are built using javascript. For that reason the right way to implement the feature you want is with javascript. It is not particularly difficult to learn, and you could write it yourself, or you could pay someone to write it for you. Stack is meant for code questions, not general information questions, or tutorials. You can find this information in other places on the internet.

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to figure out is whether or not I can use Django with JavaScript to achieve the end goal here, rather than starting again from scratch?

Comment: You can absolutely use django for this. There are many ways of incorporating it into your design. You can put the JS at the bottom of the template, or include it from another file. This confusion is happening because you are lacking an understanding of how JS and django work together. That is something you will need to learn on your own.